# Made an MP4 recording with SimpleScreenRecorder and default player or VLC won't play it

Tags: vlc, mp4, desktop-recording

I had been using MKV and tried MP4 and would like to get it to work some way or another. I'm using Ubuntu version 14.04.

When I try to play it with the default player it says no playable data and with VLC it does nothing as if I haven't even chosen a file to play.

Comment: Open terminal and run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` to install required plugin for playing video files. Report back if you found any problem

Comment: After installing it said something about "Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer"  in it with a grey background. Not sure if it finished or not don't know how to get past it. Trie dplaying the files and they're not playing.

Comment: That's the Microsoft EULA agreement, simply press `Tab` and `Enter/Return` to agree.

Comment: Figured it out. Pressed the right arrow button and could select "OK" at the bottom. I finished installing that and the files won't play. The first MP4 recording I made actually plays in both players, but any made after that won't.

Comment: Would you mind to attach the screenshot ?

Comment: Screenshot of what?

Comment: The error that popup when you play videos...

Comment: I can't open the default player for some reason and VLC doesn't give an error message, just does nothing as if you were trying to play without selecting a file. The other player said something like "No playable data found". I also tried uploading it to YouTube to see what would happen and it said the file couldn't be processed.

Comment: Maybe corrupted file ?

Comment: Maybe. If it's corrupted, can it be fixed? And how do I stop it from happening again? The first MP4 recording I made worked and the other wouldn't play for some reason.

Comment: You may want read this to make sure if the file is really corrupted: https://superuser.com/a/100290.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same error. The solution here was change the audio code to MP3 (the default is Vorbis).